# mongo-go-driver aggregate query always return "Current": null

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongo-go

I want to sum a field by using

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id": "", 
        "count": bson.M{ "$sum": 1}}}
}
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
result, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
```

but it always return

```
"Current": null
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`Collection.Aggregate()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Aggregate) returns a [`mongo.Cursor`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor), not the "direct" result. You have to iterate over the cursor to get the result documents (e.g. with [`Cursor.Next()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.Next) and [`Cursor.Decode()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.Decode)), or use [`Cursor.All()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All) to fetch all result documents in one step.

Next, you didn't specify which field you want to sum. What you have is a simple "counting", it will return the number of documents processed. To really sum a field, you may do it with

```
"sum": bson.M{"$sum": "$fieldName"}
```

Let's see an example. Let's assume we have the following documents in Database `"example"`, in collection `"checks"`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dd6f24742be9bfe54b298cb"), "payment" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dd6f24942be9bfe54b298cc"), "payment" : 20 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dd6f48842be9bfe54b298cd"), "payment" : 4 }
```

This is how we could count the checks and sum the payments (`payment` field):

```
c := client.Database("example").Collection("checks")

pipe := []bson.M{
    {"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":   "",
        "sum":   bson.M{"$sum": "$payment"},
        "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1},
    }},
}
cursor, err := c.Aggregate(ctx, pipe)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var results []bson.M
if err = cursor.All(ctx, &results); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := cursor.Close(ctx); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(results)
```

This will output:

```
[map[_id: count:3 sum:34]]
```

The result is a slice with one element, showing `3` documents were processed, and the sum (of payments) is `34`.

Comment: can i get the results in struct form instead of []bson.M from cursor.All ?

Comment: @nanakondor Have you tried it? Yes, you can. But it must be a slice of struct or slice of pointers to struct because in general the result of an aggregation is a list of documents.