# Basic group aggregation with go mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to do a really simple aggregation with golang mongo-driver but I can't make it work...
I tried multiple solutions but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here is my code :

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
            "sender_id": req.UserID,
        }},
        bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
            "_id": bson.M{
                "receiver_id": "$receiver_id",
            },
            "last_chat": bson.M{
                "$max": "$send_at",
            },
            "message": bson.M{
                "$last": "$message",
            },
            "senderid": bson.M{
                "$last": "$sender_id",
            },
        }},
    }
    cur, err := repo.collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)
```

Where req.UserID is equal to "3ba73e3d-8a97-45e5-83d8-1680445e3975"
And this is what I have in my collection :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd9a15f3473711925c856f9"
  },
  "sender_id": "3ba73e3d-8a97-45e5-83d8-1680445e3975",
  "receiver_id": "99d22266-39db-4cf3-aa95-dee2fdb98fd0",
  "send_at": "2020-11-24 13:27:30",
  "message": "first test msg!"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fde809aeff88e561d43012b"
  },
  "sender_id": "3ba73e3d-8a97-45e5-83d8-1680445e3975",
  "receiver_id": "75d22466-39db-78f3-ad75-dee2fd5v8rd0",
  "send_at": "2020-11-28 13:27:30",
  "message": "dec test msg!"
}
```

I don't have any result for this query... I properly catch the errors but nothing !

I get results (not how I want) if I change the _id field like this :

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
        "sender_id": req.UserID,
    }},
    bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
        "_id": "$id",
        "last_chat": bson.M{
            "$max": "$send_at",
        },
        "message": bson.M{
            "$last": "$message",
        },
        "senderid": bson.M{
            "$last": "$sender_id",
        },
    }},
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you don't have a result?

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I try to loop using cur.Next() and cur.Decode() I dont have anything but if I change the _id field in my group aggregation to « $id » it returns rows correctly (but without the grouping i want to make) - Sorry if my english isnt clear...

Comment: Could you include the pipeline that does return documents? We can try comparing the two to see why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thank you again for your reactivity!
I will update my question as soon as possible!

Comment: This is the one returning documents but not how I want :
pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
            "sender_id": req.UserID,
        }},
        bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
            "_id": "$id",
            "last_chat": bson.M{
                "$max": "$send_at",
            },
            "message": bson.M{
                "$last": "$message",
            },
            "senderid": bson.M{
                "$last": "$sender_id",
            },
        }},
    }

Comment: I just edited the question for formating

Comment: I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513341/how-to-perform-aggregations-in-go-using-mongo-driver) with an aggregation similar to yours, and don't seen any big differences. I also ran your original pipeline locally and it's working. Was the change to the `_id` field the only one you made?

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the example I saw earlier and tried to remake but no succes on my side with the data structure I have (as shown above). The query doesn't return results grouped by "receiver_id" field.
Did you try the first pipeline I wrote ? What is your result when you loop through the cursor please ?

Comment: I did try the first pipeline. On decoding the results into a `bson.M`, I get `map[_id:map[receiver_id:75d22466-39db-78f3-ad75-dee2fd5v8rd0] last_chat:2020-11-28 13:27:30 message:dec test msg! senderid:3ba73e3d-8a97-45e5-83d8-1680445e3975]` and `map[_id:map[receiver_id:99d22266-39db-4cf3-aa95-dee2fdb98fd0] last_chat:2020-11-24 13:27:30 message:first test msg! senderid:3ba73e3d-8a97-45e5-83d8-1680445e3975]`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was a little bit off with the end of the year ! Happy new year !
It's really weird because I have nothing with the first pipeline and if I replace bson.M{"receiver_id": "$receiver_id"} by "$receiver_id" as I have seen in some example I get the following error : "error decoding key _id: an ObjectID string must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 36)"...

Comment: I think I made a mistake telling you I have nothing, I think I wasn't catching the error properly because now if I try the first pipeline with exactly the same syntax and data I have the following error : "error decoding key _id: cannot decode embedded document into an ObjectID"

Comment: How are you trying to decode the results? It seems like you may be using `receiver_id` or `sender_id` as an ObjectId which is invalid.

Comment: Yes I try but it doesn't return anything, it seems like it wants an ObjectID for the "_id" field in the "$group" clause but I want to group by receiver_id which is a string... What I don't understand is that I am following the examples I have seen online and you have a result without error with the same pipeline!
I also tried downgrading my go mongodb driver to v1.2.0 and v1.0.0 but nothing different